# python3 formalchemy alternative

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, formalchemy

Is there a FormAlchemy alternative for Python3.2? I'm specifically interested in using it in conjunction with Pyramid.

I'm getting syntax errors when setting up FormAlchemy1.3.3 so their latest release is not compatible.

Comment: Apparently this question is irrelevant. I would say it is relevant for anyone who wants to use a standardized form generator in an application using Python3 and SQLAlchemy. That would likely be quite a few people since the latest Pyramid release works with Python3. Can anyone explain the close vote to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At time of writing there is none